# Implement custom stack canary handling without the standard library

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow

I am trying to implement stack canaries manually and without the standard library. Therefore I have created a simple PoC with the help of [this guide](https://wiki.osdev.org/Stack_Smashing_Protector) from the OSDev wiki. The article suggests that a simple implementation must provide the `__stack_chk_guard` variable and the `__stack_chk_fail()` handler.

However, when I compile using GCC and provide the `-fstack-protector-all` flag, the executable does not contain any stack canary check at all. What am I missing to get GCC to include the stack canary logic?

```
gcc -Wall -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -fstack-protector-all -g -m64 -o poc main.c customlib.h
```

***main.c***

```
#include "customlib.h"

#define STACK_CHK_GUARD (0xDEADBEEFFFFFFFF & ~0xFF)
uintptr_t __stack_chk_guard = STACK_CHK_GUARD;

__attribute__((noreturn)) void __stack_chk_fail()
{
    __exit(123);
    while(1);
}

int main()
{
    __attribute__((unused)) char buffer[16];

    for (size_t index = 0; index < 32; index++)
    {
        buffer[index] = 'A';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***customlib.h***

This code is mostly irrelevant and is just necessary so that the program can be compiled and linked correctly.

```
typedef unsigned long int size_t;
typedef unsigned long int uintptr_t;

size_t __syscall(size_t arg1, size_t arg2, size_t arg3, size_t arg4, size_t arg5, size_t arg6)
{
    asm("int $0x80\n"
        : "=a"(arg1)
        : "a"(arg1), "b"(arg2), "c"(arg3), "d"(arg4), "S"(arg5), "D"(arg6));
    return arg1;
}

void _exit(int exit_code)
{
    __syscall(1, exit_code, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    while(1);
}

extern int main();

void _start()
{
    main();
    _exit(0);
}
```

*GCC version 10.2.0, Linux 5.10.36-2-MANJARO GNU/Linux*

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465014/gcc-generate-canary-or-not

Comment: @4386427 `-fstack-protector-all` should force GCC to add the check to any function, also the buffer in `main()` is larger than 8 bytes, thus there is no reason to omit the check from an optimization standpoint.

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/z/bnd6ehxEY) seems to be emitting the canary checks correctly.

Comment: @Hasturkun thanks for pointing this out. I have now verified that the code indeed works when using a VM and a different GCC installation. What could be the issue here? When compiling on Manjaro, the canary checks are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Perhaps allocated frame size is too large, have you tried increasing the overflow from 32 to 64?

Comment: @yugr shouldn't the frame size be irrelevant when providing `-fstack-protector-all`? Nonetheless, I have also tried the same buffer size with a 128 and 256 byte overflow - same result.

Comment: Assuming the GCC package you're using in Manjaro is based on the one from Arch, [this patch](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/f5e1c54220db0c659a8db7f6d62be86356ec8aca/trunk/fs64270.patch) looks relevant (forces `-fno-stack-protector` when disabling standard libraries). Does adding an explicit `-fstack-protector` do anything?

Comment: @Hasturkun explicitly stating `-fstack-protector` does not work either, but I think your guess is correct and the Arch flavored GCC does not like custom SSPs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Arch gcc package (which the Manjaro package is based on) [is turning off `-fstack-protector` when building without the standard library](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/f5e1c54220db0c659a8db7f6d62be86356ec8aca/trunk/fs64270.patch) (Done for Arch bug [64270](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64270)).

This behavior is apparently also present in Gentoo.

I haven't tried this, but I believe you should be able to dump the GCC specs using `gcc -dumpspecs` into a file, keeping only the section `*cc1_options`, removing `%{nostdlib|nodefaultlibs|ffreestanding:-fno-stack-protector}` from it, and passing it to gcc with `gcc -specs=your_spec_file`.

Alternately, you can rebuild the gcc package with this patch removed.

Comment: The recent update to `gcc (GCC) 11.1.0` has also fixed the issue.